# Функция для количества случайных вытаскиваний с вероятностью

Tags: оптимизация, случайные-числа, статистика, генерация-случайных-данных

Из всего в мат я не могу понять только распределения.

Задача: есть массив из Len элементов. Каждый элемент может быть вытащен с вероятностю P. Нужна функция, которая каждый раз возвращает случайное количество вытащенных элементов (0..Len). Что-то вроде автомата для вытаскивания игрушек, где каждую игрушку пробуют вытащить 1 раз. В данный момент просто обхожу массивы и пробую вытащить каждый элемент, но это не оптимально. Даже получил эмпирические данные. Но не могу подобрать распределение, которое выдавало тот же результат. Len и P могут получать произвольные значения. Даже самое близкое станд.распр имеет странное несоответствие.

Вот такой результат нужен:

вероятность 50%

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вероятность 10%

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я ничего не понял.

Comment: добавил аналогию с автоматом для вытаскивания игрушек

Comment: [Биномиальное распределение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хрустальный шар не подводит, то вам нужно [биномиальное распределение](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: Посмотрел разные реализации. Везде используется полноценный цикл **for i from 1 to len**, что очень неоптимально и ничем не отличается от моего первого решения. Извините за незнание, но разве нет алгоритма лучше O(n) ?

Comment: Вы серьёзно?  Ваше решение выполняет runs проходов. Расчёт по формуле требует len вычислений функции вероятности (через биномиальные коэффициенты)

Comment: всё правильно, я делал runs только для графика. Сами числа я получаю одним проходом. Проблема в том, что у меня Len = десятки тысяч.
Как я понял, даже numpy так делает. Что ж, попробую просто отсекать низкую вероятность

Comment: Кто-то из нас чего-то не понимает, может быть - я.  Если вам нужно получить len значений - как это можно сделать быстрее len?

Comment: нужно всего **1** случайное значение по бином. распределению

Comment: Я не знаю, что такое `1 случайное значение по бином. распределению`. Величину, приведённую в последних столбцах таблиц в вопросе (0.001, 0.010, 0.044, 0.117. 0.205...), получаете по формуле функции вероятности для БР.

Comment: функция должна просто выдать одно число N, где вероятность каждого значения задана БР. То же самое, что getRandomInteger(0, Len), но разные числа выпадают с разной вероятн.